# Parsing an NSMutableArray for URLs

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rss, nsmutablearray

I am attempting to parse multiple urls for an RSS reader for iPhone. I have managed to create an RSS feed that draws cells from a single url, but I would like for my table to have cells from multiple urls simultaneously. Here is what I have right now that does not work...anyone see any possible solutions/problems?

```
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feed1"];
 NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feed2"];

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     [feeds addObject:[url absoluteString]]; // Convert NSURL to NSString
     [feeds addObject:[url2 absoluteString]];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url forKey:@"feeds"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url2 forKey:@"feeds"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"feeds"]];

 for(NSString *urlString in array)
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]); // Crete NSURL from NSString

 parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:feeds];
```

Comment: don't use NSUserDefaults to pass around data.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set one value per key in NSUserDefaults. 
So the second call overrides the first one 
you could try :
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:feeds forKey:@"feeds"];

instead of:
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url forKey:@"feeds"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:url2 forKey:@"feeds"];

but anyway passing data with NSUserDefaults isn't the best strategy

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    [feeds addObject:[url absoluteString]]; // Convert NSURL to NSString
    [feeds addObject:[url2 absoluteString]];
```

is equivalent to

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    [feeds addObject:[url absoluteString]]; // Convert NSURL to NSString
}
[feeds addObject:[url2 absoluteString]];
```

you want

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    [feeds addObject:[url absoluteString]]; // Convert NSURL to NSString
    [feeds addObject:[url2 absoluteString]];
}
```

---

```
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:feeds];
```

You cannot simply substitute an NSURL object with an array of NSURL objects.

create a parser for each url.

---

As said by Leonard: Don't use NSUserDefaults to pass around data. Use properties.